# Set condition on a segue function swift

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, segue

> In a single button, i put both alart system and a pop up view. If the text fields are blank then it will send an alart. If everything is okay then it will show popup view. Alart system and pop up is conflicting. How do I set conditon to segue function when to perform or not?

The function is not written proper. I can understand. But I am confused writing it. How do i call the overrride func?

```
func stateCondition(state: Bool) {
    if state {
        print("Entered into the state") //entering into the func
        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            if segue.identifier == "info"{
                _ = segue.destination as! InfoViewController
            }
            if segue.identifier == "popUp" {
                let vc = segue.destination as! PopUpViewController
                vc.age = Double(ageTextField.text!)!
                vc.gender = genderTextField.text!
                vc.bmi = Double(bmiLabel.text!)!

                print("Entered into the segue") //is not entering into this func

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read the code and comments. 
**First** of all, the method `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` must not be in another method. Somehow you managed to squeeze it in `func stateCondition(state: Bool)` . **Second** you are not calling `performSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: self)` anywhere. You probably should :) Check out the code, hope it helps. I remember my first segue, it took me some time to understand what is going on.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var ageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet private var genderTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet private var bmiLabel: UILabel!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        // 3
        // This method gets called and there you do your stuff with respective VCs
        if segue.identifier == "info", let infoViewController = segue.destination as? InfoViewController {
            // 3.1
            // If the identifer is set to INFO then you go to the InfoViewController and assigne message
            infoViewController.message = "Some fields are empty"

        } else if segue.identifier == "popUp", let popUpViewController = segue.destination as? PopUpViewController {
            // 3.2
            // If the identifer is set to POPUP then you go to PopUpViewController and assign age, gender and bmi
            popUpViewController.age = "33"
            popUpViewController.gender = "male"
            popUpViewController.bmi = "20"
        } else {
            print("Identifer is none of the above")
        }
    }

    @IBAction private func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        // 1.
        // First you need to figure out where you want to take the user
        // You do that in the method getSegueIdentifier() where you get the identifier
        let identifier = getSegueIdentifier()

        // 2.
        // Then you performSegue with that identifer
        performSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: self)
    }

    private func getSegueIdentifier() -> String {

        if ageTextField.text?.isEmpty == true && genderTextField.text?.isEmpty == true && bmiLabel.text?.isEmpty == true {
            return "info"
        } else {
            return "popUp"
        }
    }
}

class InfoViewController: UIViewController {

    var message = ""

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        showAlert()
    }

    func showAlert() {
         // show alert with message
        print(message)
    }
}

class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

    var age = ""
    var gender = ""
    var bmi = ""

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        showPopUp()
    }

    func showPopUp() {
        // show popUp with age gender and bmi
        print(age, gender, bmi)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is general misunderstanding: You must not call `prepare(for segue` – besides the syntax is wrong anyway – the function is called by the framework just before the segue is performed.

You probably mean something like

```
func stateCondition(state: Bool) {
    if state {
        print("Entered into the state") //entering into the func
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "info", sender: nil)
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "popUp", sender: nil)
    }
}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popUp" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! PopUpViewController
        vc.age = Double(ageTextField.text!)!
        vc.gender = genderTextField.text!
        vc.bmi = Double(bmiLabel.text!)!

        print("Entered into the segue") //is not entering into this func
    }
}
```